# What is a word for "made more complicated"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that means "made more complicated/complex" but not as simple as "complexified", which I don't think is a very popular word.

Example usage:

> The inclusion of Shichimi togarashi, a Japanese spice, "complexified"
> the already intricate mixture of ingredients.

Comment: The word you want is "Complicated".

Comment: Within your context, *enriched* or *deepened* would be good choices. In general, complexity is good in food, but *complicated* means 'made things more complicated than necessary' (and thus, bad).

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of Shichimi togarashi, a Japanese spice, "**complicated**" by the already intricate mixture of ingredients, **intensified** the recipe, taste, situation.....

or

The inclusion of Shichimi togarashi, a Japanese spice, "**intensified**" by the already intricate mixture of ingredients ** further complicated** the recipe, taste, situation, etc.....

or

The inclusion of Shichimi togarashi, a Japanese spice, **further complicated** the already intricate mixture of ingredients